# Eclipse multi module project dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

I have multi module java project as follows:

```
top_level_project

pom.xml

  (...)

  <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>

  <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>

  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>

    <module>module1</module>

    <module>module2</module>

  </modules>



/module1

  pom.xml

    (...)

    <parent>

      <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>

      <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>

      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    </parent>

    <dependencies>

     <dependency>

        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>

     </dependency>

    </dependencies>

  /src/main/java

  .project

/module2

  pom.xml

    (...)

    <parent>

      <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>

      <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>

      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    </parent>   

  /src/main/java

  .project
```

I used Eclipse Kepler & Luna.

Issue is slf4j dependency added in module1 is not recognized by eclipse(this is true for all dependencies).  I checked Parent project -> Java Build Path -> Library where Maven dependency cannot be seen or added.

Also, right clicking module1 -> Properties, I don't have option of Java build path.

Parent project -> Java Build Path -> Source tab: I see folders listed as `top_level_project/module1/src/main/java`.  I left default output folder at `top_level_project/bin`.

Project facet is Java 1.7.

Executing maven goals works just fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the project have Maven nature (little M in the top left corner of project icon)? Did you try <right-click-menu>->Maven->Update Project?

Comment: Yes ( I included this info in edit but can't see it)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to this.  Click on `top_level_project`.  From menu, select File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects.  Select `module1` etc. and click OK.

What this does is add sub project in workspace at same level as `top_level_project`.  I expect it to remain under `top_level_project` since `module1` is sub project, but this solution works as `module1` is recognized as Maven project and all Maven dependencies are included.